# Momentjs with progressbar multiple instances not working

Tags: jquery, momentjs, progress-bar

What I want is make each of the **all-timer** div to get it's separate progressbar based on the start/end time.

```
<div class="all-timer">
    <div class="start_timer">00:00</div>
    <div class="end_timer">23:50</div>

    <div id="pg-bar" class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="all-timer">
    <div class="start_timer">1:00</div>
    <div class="end_timer">20:50</div>

    <div id="pg-bar" class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="all-timer">
    <div class="start_timer">2:00</div>
    <div class="end_timer">21:50</div>

    <div id="pg-bar" class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
</div>



$(document).ready(function(){
        
        var start_time = $(this).find('.start_timer').html();
        var end_time = $(this).find('.end_timer').html();
        var start = moment(start_time, 'H:mm'); 
        var end = moment(end_time, 'H:mm'); 
        var formattedPercentage = 0;
      
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
        var now = moment();
        var percentage = now.diff(start) / end.diff(start) * 100;

        if (percentage > 100) {
          formattedPercentage = 100;
          clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
          formattedPercentage = percentage.toFixed(2);
        }
        // Use formattedPercentage as you need
        $('#pg-bar .progress-bar').width(formattedPercentage+'%').html(formattedPercentage+'%')

        }, 500);

});
```

What's wrong with code?  (You're permitted to give me a knock)

Why does my momentjs picks and load the progressbar for the first div (00:00 - 23:50) and repeat for same percentage for the other two div when the other two div's have different times that's 1:00 - 20:50 and 2:00 - 21:50.

Thanks in advance for your time

**[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nanatuts/s7mgnxbt/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

You use the same name identificator for get the domNode of the dates and the progress bars.

I give an unique id for every single block of "timer", and I used this id in jQuery for get a specific element like start date, end date and progress bar

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const groups = $('div[id^="time"]');

  for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    const start_time = $(`#time${i}>.start_timer`).html();
    const end_time = $(`#time${i}>.end_timer`).html();
    console.log(start_time)
    console.log(end_time)

    const progress_bar = $(`#time${i}>.progress>.progress-bar`);

    const start = moment(start_time, 'H:mm').tz("America/Los_Angeles");
    const end = moment(end_time, 'H:mm').tz("America/Los_Angeles");

    let formattedPercentage = 0;

    const interval = setInterval(function() {
      const now = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
      const percentage = now.diff(start) / end.diff(start) * 100;

      if (percentage > 100) {
        formattedPercentage = 100;
        clearInterval(interval);
      } else {
        formattedPercentage = percentage.toFixed(2);
      }

      progress_bar.width(formattedPercentage + '%').html(formattedPercentage + '%')

    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>2016</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data-1970-2030.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="time0" class="all-timer">
    <div class="start_timer">00:00</div>
    <div class="end_timer">23:50</div>

    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="time1" class="all-timer">
    <div class="start_timer">1:00</div>
    <div class="end_timer">20:50</div>

    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="time2" class="all-timer">
    <div class="start_timer">2:00</div>
    <div class="end_timer">21:50</div>

    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow it works like charm, Sorry for the late reply; Was out of town, How about how to add timezone, I added as example: 
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
But seems not to work.

Comment: I need this to work any timezone of my choice but its not working for me.

Comment: What is the error? I update the answare including moment-timezone but I'm not sure that is your problem. Can you share a working snippet of your code (with the problem) on jsfiddle o similar?

Comment: My bad i didn't see the code's been updated, Thanks man, Its working exactly the way i want it.